# for loop does not execute twice

Tags: javascript

```
 createModelView: function (obj,vitalslength,headerValue) {                     
    for(i = 0, vitalsLen = vitalslength; i < vitalsLen; i++) {    
      // Do some logic    
      }    
   }
```

Two Questions

1. Where should i place my return statement for the function. If i place inside the for loop will it work.
2. When i call this function `Obj.createModelView(arguments);`  Why does it not execute twice or n number of times depending upon the vitalsLength. `It only executes once.`

Comment: Where do you want the `return` statement to be placed? And what's `arguments`? And why are you creating an alias for `vitalslength`?

Comment: You should have a `var` before your `i`, otherwise you're going to be polluting a namespace. Why do you have a length variable which has exactly the same value as another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible issues:

First make sure to declare the two variables before the for loop

```
var i=0, vitalsLen=0;
```

And also check to make sure that vitalslength is a number. You can do that with `isNaN` or a `typeof` check.

```
if (isNaN(vitalslength))
  alert("vitalsLength is not a number");
```

One of these may or maybe not be causing the issue, let me know.

Also... I can't remember if it's the same in javascript as it's in some other languages, 
but `++i` is more efficient to use than `i++`.

As for the two questions:

1. It can be put after the for loop, if you really want one.
2. Hopefully the above will fix it

Answer (score 2):

To 1.: If you place an unconditional `return` statement in the loop, exactly what you described in 2. will happen: the loop will be executed only once. Therefore, you should place your `return` statement *after* the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
createModelView: function (obj,vitalslength,headerValue) {                     
    for(var i = 0; i < vitalslength; i++) {    
        // Do some logic    
    }   
    return; 
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to have a blank return at the end?

Comment: I imagine it wouldn't be blank in his application. He'd probably return something defined inside the `// do some logic` block - just a structure example.

Answer (score 2):

If you place `return` inside the `for` loop than it will execute only once. Since `return` asks the function to stop executing further and return the value you asked it to.

You may have put `return` inside the `for` loop that is why it executes only once.

Answer (score 0):

(1) No, it will not work if you put the return statement in the loop. If you place it inside the loop then the function will be returned in the first loop. The return statement exits the called obj.createModelView() function.

```
createModelView: function (obj, vitalslength, headerValue) {
    var i, vitalsLen = vitalsLength;    
    for(i = 0; i < vitalsLen; i += 1) {
        // Do some logic
    }
    return;
}
```

(2) The function is not executed twice (or n-times) when you call the function once. To call the obj.createModelView function n-times you would have to put the function call in a loop.

```
var i, n = 4;
for(i=0; i < n; i += 1) {
    obj.createModelView();
}
```